# how to add pandas Timestamp to sqlite3?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pandas

I defined a DateTimeField though Django as:

```
class test(models.Model):
     t = models.DateTimeField()
```

In pandas, I have a dataframe as

```
a=DataFrame(date_range('2014-1-1','2014-1-2'))
type(a.ix[0,0])
```

which shows: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

When I tried to insert the data through:

```
stmt="insert into dry_powder_test('t')  values(?)"
cnx = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
cnx.executemany(stmt, a.to_records(index=False).tolist())
cnx.commit()
```

There is no error. but

```
 test.objects.get(pk=1).t
```

gives me empty result. Although in the db I actually see

```
(u'project_test', 't', 1388534400000000000L)
```

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Your django model has a field t, which is type django.model.DateTimeField, and you save to database pandas.data_range, which is converted implicite to miliseconds from 1970.

1. Why you mix Django and Pandas, while you have no basics about Python?
2. Why your class name doesn't start with capital letter?
3. Why you write raw sql rather than using Django model?

--- edit ---
Hello again,

I've solved your problem. I've used django orm to create valid model, so:

```
[1]: a1 = test()

[2]: a1.t

[3]: a1.t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 26, 13, 0, 0, 775217)
```

Then i've checked DB:

```
$./manage.py dbshell
sqlite> select * from polls_test;
1|1388534400000000000
2|1388620800000000000
3|2012-02-26 13:00:00.775217
```

Comment: 1. I don't see anything wrong with mixing Django and Pandas. I need Pandas to do calculations and Django to admin and display data.

2. I wrote the test class as an example here.

3. I am inputting data from Pandas to sqlite3.

If you ignore the Django part, just inserting Pandas's timestamp is problematic with sqlite3

Comment: Using Django to display data is like shooting to fly with cannon. You should better use ipython notebok: http://ipython.org/notebook.html